# How to convert a cmake header file with comments into a TSV/CSV file?

Tags: python, c, bash, parsing, cmakelists-options

I have a number of cmake header files from which I would like to extract the comments and the `cmakedefine`, into a CSV (or TSV) file.

The typical input looks like this:

```cpp
/**
 * 1st Multi-line brief description of what the following 
 * cmakedefine does.
 *
 * Second more complicated multi-line full description, of <c>SOMETHING</c> to be enabled in the
 * configuration.
 *
 * Possibly additional lines of full description.
 */
#cmakedefine SOMETHING
```

The 1st step output is to get is this:

```
SOMETHING
1st Multi-line brief description of what the following cmakedefine does.
Second more complicated multi-line full description , of <c>SOMETHING</c> to be enabled in the configuration. Possibly additional lines of full description.
...
```

Ultimately the output I am looking to get is this:

```
SOMETHING, "1st Multi-line brief description of what the following cmakedefine does.", "Second more complicated multi-line full description, of <c>SOMETHING</c> to be enabled in the configuration. Possibly additional lines of full description."

SOMETHING_ELSE, "Brief description", "Long Description"
```

(The columns headers can be implied to be: `cmakedefine, Brief_Description, Long_Description`.)

I have tried unsuccessfully to do this in **sed** which was not a good way to spend my time. I have also tried with **awk** without success.  At this point I don't care what tools to use, and just want to get the job done. But I think maybe Python could be better used for this.

Things to Note:

- all comments starts with an empty `/**`.
- all `Brief` comments start with `\ * \` , possible on multiple lines.
- `Brief` and `Long` comments are separated with an empty comment line `\ *`.
- all `Long` comments can have multiple paragraphs (as shown), in a similar way.
- The related `cmakedefine` is following the comments.

---

**UPDATE:**

The cmake file was more complicated than I fist expected, because:

1. There are many irrelevant *stand-alone* comments that has nothing to do with the ones just preceding the `#cmakedefine`.
2. There are some comments that are followed by several `#cmakedefine`.
3. Sometimes the comments even include the string `#cmakedefine`, commas and other characters, like `<c>`.
4. Sometimes there are single (`'`) and double (`"`) quotes in the comments.

A more complicated file could look like this:

```cpp
/**
 * Only a "Brief" comment
 */ 
#cmakedefine SIMPLE

/**
 * 1st multi-line Brief description of what the following 
 * cmakedefine does.
 *
 * 2nd more complicated multi-line Full description, of <c>SOMETHING</c> to be enabled in the
 * configuration.
 *
 * [Sometimes] additional paragraph-1 of full description, 
 * going on several lines.
 *
 * [Sometimes] additional paragraph-2 of full "description", 
 * going on several lines. (double quoted)
 *
 * ...
 * [Sometimes] additional paragraph-N of full 'description', 
 * going on several lines. (single quoted)
 */
#cmakedefine SOMETHING

/**
 * Some useless unrelated comment
 */ 

/**
 * 1st Multi-line brief description of what the following 
 * cmakedefine does.
 *
 * Second more complicated multi-line full description, of <c>SOMETHING</c> to be enabled in the
 * configuration.
 *
 * Possibly additional lines of full description.
 */
#cmakedefine SOMETHING_ELSE
#cmakedefine ANOTHER_SOMETHING
```

Comment: `do this in sed which was not a good way to spend my time` +1 Do you consider writing standardized comments format and just using doxygen?

Comment: I guess these files were made to conform with *doxygen*, but I have never used it, so I don't really know what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks nice in AWK, overall the complexity depends on how different inputs there are. Here's something to get you started:

```
awk '
gsub(/^ \* */, "") {
    if ($0 == "/") {
        // end - to nothing
    } else if ($0) {
        comment = comment (comment ? " " : "") $0;
    } else if (!firstline) {
        firstline = comment
        comment = ""
    }
}
gsub(/^#cmakedefine /, ""){
    print $0 ", \"" firstline "\", \"" comment "\"";
    fistline = 0
    comment = ""
}
' <<EOF
/**
 * 1st Multi-line brief description of what the following 
 * cmakedefine does.
 *
 * Second more complicated multi-line full description <c>SOMETHING</c> to be enabled in the
 * configuration.
 *
 * Possibly additional lines of full description.
 */
#cmakedefine SOMETHING
EOF
```

outputs:

```
SOMETHING, "1st Multi-line brief description of what the following  cmakedefine does.", "Second more complicated multi-line full description <c>SOMETHING</c> to be enabled in the configuration. Possibly additional lines of full description."
```

Here is a nice awk tutorial https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

The next step would be adding some state, like not ouptutting an empty comment, maybe clearing the input more with some regex, and properly quoting for csv or tsv or what you want your format to be and as complexity goes up answering why not python and json.

Comment: That almost worked. However, it doesn't like commas (`,`) in the lines, and then puts the next line in a new CSV field. Sorry my example didn't show that, but I added it now.  Also, it didn't concatenate subsequent lines (separated by empty comment line) in long description, and treat them as separate CSV columns. Maybe it just got confused from the lines before with commas?

Comment: "The next step would be adding....properly quoting for csv or tsv .... answering why not python and json". There is also a link to awk tutorial. Awk manual can also be found online. Newer awk has also ability to load libraries like csv from gawkextlib. (and then, why not python with import csv.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're tempted to use [python](/questions/tagged/python) with *regex* :

```
import re
from itertools import groupby
import pandas as pd #pip install pandas

pat = r"/\*\*\n(.*?)\*/\n(?=#cmakedefine (\w+))"

with open("input.cmake", "r") as f:
    d = {
        m.group(2): [
            comment.strip("* ")
            for comment in m.group(1).split("\n") if m
        ] for m in re.finditer(pat, f.read(), re.DOTALL)
    }

# to concatenate the splitted comments
for cmake,com in d.items():
    d[cmake] = [
        " ".join(g) for k, g in groupby(com, key=lambda x: x!= "") if k
    ]

# making the [TC]SV
(
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index")
        .apply(lambda x: x.add('"').radd('"')) # could be optional
        .to_csv("output.csv", sep=",", header=False, quoting=3, escapechar="\\")
) # use `sep="\t"` and change the extension of the file if you need a TSV
```

> Regex : [[*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/reUoMr/1)]

Output (*in a tabular format*) :

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SOMETHING | 1st Multi-line brief description of what the following cmakedefine does. | Second more complicated multi-line full description of , SOMETHING to be enabled in the configuration. | Possibly additional lines of full description. |
| SOMETHING_ELSE | Brief description | Long Description |  |

Comment: Thanks! Very cool, especially the RegEx Demo site. I noticed your script skipped the `<c>` parts, which is ok, but I would like to know why that happened? Also, updated OP with a more complete example. I'm not asking you to handle that, but perhaps describe your code a little more detail, as I am not very good at brain compiling lambdas. How could I put all additional lines as *one* Long Description?

Comment: In the output I put in my answer, I used `df.to_markdown()`, that's why the `<c>` tag is hidden but don't worry, in the csv/tsv, the tags are preserved (*you can also try to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76972082/edit) the answer to show them up*). And regarding your second question, you can slightly adjust the listcomp in the first bloc by using `" ".join(comment.strip("* ")... ` and remove the second bloc that starts with `for cmake,com in d.items():..` You'll have a single column that holds all the descriptions.

Comment: Nope, that didn't quite work. I want column 0 (as above) to be as it is, and column 1 to shown what is now in column 1-N. Your suggested modification put (almost!) everything in column 0 and only few in column 1. Or maybe I put the *join* ending `)` in the wrong place?

Comment: Also, I just noticed that it skips the 1st `single comment + #cmakedefine SIMPLE`, from my updated example.